# what could be the reason made a program running on two compute with a big different ipc(instrument per second)?

Tags: linux, performance, tensorflow

```
OS:  Linux 4.4.198-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6148 CPU @ 2.40GHz * 4
MEM: 376 GB
```

I have a program(do some LSTM model inference based on TensorFlow 1.14)，it runs on two machines with the same hardware, one got a bad performance while the other got a better one(about `10x` diff).

I used intel pqos tool diagnosed that two processes and got a big different IPC number (one is `0.07` while the other one is `2.5`), both processes are binding on some specified CPU core, and each machine payload does not heavy. This problem appears two weeks ago, before that this bad machine works as well, history command shows nothing configuration changed.

I checked many environ information, including the kernel, fs, process scheduler, io scheduler, program, and libraries md5, they are the same, the bad computer iLo show none error, the program mainly burns the CPU.

I used sysbench to test two machines(cpu & memory) which show about `25%` performance difference, the bad machine does prime calculation is slower. Could it be some hardware problem?

I don't know what is the root cause resulted in the difference in IPC (equaled to performance), How can I dig into the situation?

Comment: what else is running? what does top show? what niceness?

Comment: nothing else is running on two machines, top shows the binding CPU core 100% usage(almost userspace), niceness is the same value 0.

Comment: then use perf to profile

Comment: yes, I perf profile as well,  perf top shows the same stack and the cost time proportion is almost the same, perf stat present different cycles while the slow one used more cycles within the same running time.

Comment: some hardware semi-failure? One harddrive is fully working, the other has some problems? (probably not). Do you control the machines, could you swap one piece of hardware at a time between machines and see when the problem moves to the other machine? (probably not, but again, just an idea) ;-( Good luck!

Comment: And have  you verified that all `lib.so` files that are being used dynamically by the system are the same version numbers? Good luck.

Comment: For that big a difference maybe one machine is HDD the other SSD?

Comment: @shellter, I have checked the dep lib.so files at runtime, they are same.

Comment: @stark, they are HDD, the write latency almost the same, and I made tmpfs instead the hdd, but the performance is bad as well.

Comment: @shellter, the problem appears two weeks ago, before that this machine works as well.

Comment: You seem to be ahead of me on all o this, but given that you have a definite start date for the problem, I assume you've looked at all of your logs. While I was looking at other possibilties, I would run `find / -print -ls > mach[1,2].files` and then `diff` them. (There is an option to avoid NFS/etc remote mounts, but I'm not sure what that is right now). Again thinking of hardware, does this process rely on a network card, either for communication or to write data to a SAN (I guess not given your /tmpfs comment above). Running out of ideas ;-( . Good luck!

Comment: And finallly(?) , it will help others generate ideas if you can tell us if you have control over these machines or if they belong to an organization and that any fixes (besides software) would have to be done by sysadmins. (Maybe add that the the body of the Q, rather than reply in comments, as this is getting rather long). (Can  you upgrade to Linux 5.x.x to see i the problem remains?). Good luck.

Comment: The calculation mainly burns the CPU, it including a few IO(I have used tmpfs instead that, perf top shows the read and write latency is very low), the calculation still slow. I read the ILO  and find none error, after restart the bad server the problem still exists. I wonder if the CPU or memory is not working properly, but I don't know how to prove that.